# How to pass parameters in a php script defined in composer.json which is executed in a container

Tags: php, docker, shell, composer-php

I have a php script defined in `composer.json` which is executed in a Docker container. I need to be able to pass parameters from the host to the container where the script is executed. The intuitive syntax `"docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh -c \"php cli.php;\" --"` does not seem to work.

Comment: Because you're running a `sh` command, not a PHP command. The additional args go the `sh`, not `php`. Get rid of the `sh` command and run `php` directly.

Comment: What are you talking about? I want to run a php script from the shell of the container. @Sammitch

Comment: Let me clarify things again: 1. I need to run a script within the container 2. While I am on the host machine 3. Via a composer defined script 4. And be able to pass arguments

Comment: And I am saying `docker exec -it container_name php cli.php arg arg` should work, you don't need `sh` in the mix.

Comment: Bear in mind that containerized applications are shared with people that have minimal or no knowledge of such technology, like ui designers eg, here's a script that needs to be aliased (with simpler syntax) for such people to run as `composer cli arg1 arg2` as it calculates a hex value based on input for some internal cases. On the other hand even if this is a more complicated approach, it's not an invalid one as it's actually doable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Technology in many ways is about interfacing, so a simpler syntax that doesn't expose internal complexity can be a valid approach.

Answer (score -1):

The only workaround that I've managed to find, is to define within `composer.json` a predefined set of expected arguments as such: `$1 $2` which makes the full script declaration: `"cli"`:`"docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh -c \"php cli.php \\$1 \\$2;\" --"`.

It can then be called with: `$ composer cli arg1 arg2`